# how to create a file automatically?

Tags: bash, shell-script, touch

I'm trying to create a script that can:

- look for a file containing "foobar" as name
- a script is executed on this file and the output must be stored in a new CSV file, which is created automatically and which has the same name as the searched file. The only difference is that the extension is changed to CSV.

This is my script. :

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# search for file containing "foobar" as a name in the directory
for file in /home/user/Documents/* ;
do 

if [[ "$file" == *"$foobar"* ]]; then
touch  /home/user/Documents/collectCSV/csv1.csv
# executing script of modelising foobar file ==> extract some data from $foobar file and insert it in the
# created file csv1.csv
/home/user/scriptModelise.pl  $file >> /home/user/Documents/collectCSV/csv1.csv


else 
echo "foobar file not found" 
fi

done
```

The problem is that this method of creating a file is static. I didn't succeed in making the file creation automatic. I mean when it finds a foobar file it will be modelised in a new file that will be created.

Any help please ?

Comment: just to confirm I understood correctly; you want to create a new file with another filename (eg. adding a postfix) if a file with a certain filename (defined into foobar variable) already exists. Right?

Comment: I want to conserve the same name just change the extension..Thanks for the point ! I've edited the post .

Comment: is original extension always the same ? you can use `$(basename "$file" .data)` to strip the `.data` extension.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @archemar , no I want to change the extension and conserve the file name.

Comment: I want to automate creating new files having  names of the searched files (contaning "foobar" string ) with an another extension : csv . I hope it's clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
for file in *"$foobar"*
do
   dest="$(echo $file| sed -e 's/\(.*\)\.[^\.]*$/\1.csv/' )"
   if test -f "$file" 
   then 
       /home/user/scriptModelise.pl  "$file" >> /home/user/Documents/collectCSV/$dest
   else
     echo "no $foobar file"
   fi
done
```

where

- `\(.*\)\.[^\.]*$` capture a pattern with any char, (end of pattern) followed by a dot, non dot till end of line
- `\1.csv` insert pattern found, add .csv
- `*"$foobar"*` will expand to litteral `*foobar*` (with proper value) if no matching file are found. hence the need for `test -f "$file"`

Edit:

- `\(.*\)\.[^\.]*$`  (left hand side: finding pattern(s) )

split into ( _ are place holder )

- `__.*__________` a pattern with any char (dot has a special meaning: any char)
- `__.*__\._______`  a pattern with any char, followed by a dot (escaped dot is a plain dot)
- `__.*__\.[^\.]*$` pattern with any char, (end of pattern) followed by a dot, non dot (`[^\.]*`) till end of line (dollar sign is special for end of line)
- `\(__\)__________` capture the first part of pattern.
- `\1.csv` (right hand side, what to do)
- `\1____` `\1` match what was within first `\( \)` , `\2` for second and so on, use `&` for whole pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot @archemar , your answer saved my day ! I've done some changes , it works perfectly :)

Comment: could you please , explain me this pattern ` \(.*\)\.[^\.]*$ ` . Because I'm manipulating another extension of files which is similar to `.tar.gz` And I want to modify this pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Easier with `zsh` (note that you're already using `zsh` syntax when you're leaving your variables unquoted like that):

```sh
#! /bin/zsh -
files=(/home/user/Documents/*foobar*(N))
if (($#files)) {
  ret=0
  for f ($files) {
    /home/user/scriptModelise.pl $f > $f:h/collectCSV/$f:t:r.csv || ret=$?
  }
  exit $ret
} else {
  echo >&2 No non-hidden foobar file
  exit 1
}
```

- Like in `csh`, `$f:h` is the head (dirname), `$f:t` the tail (basename), `$f:r` the root (extension removed).
- `((arithmetic expression))` like in `ksh` evaluates the *arithmetic expression* and returns true if it resolves to a non-zero value.
- `$#array`, reminiscent of `ksh`'s `${#string}` gives the length of the array in number of elements. In `ksh`/`bash` where arrays are not really a distinct type, you need `${#array[@]}` for that as `${#array}` would be the length (in number of characters) of the element of indice 0.
- `(N)`: glob qualifier that says to expand to nothing if there's no match
- `$f`, `$files`: contrary to other Bourne-like shells, variables don't need to be quoted (as long as they don't contain empty values). In other shells (ksh, bash, yash), you'd need `"$f"` and `"${files[@]}"`.

Comment: whoa,  those `if ((condition)) {.... } else {...}` are   C style syntax - I never knew you could do that in a shell script - nice!

Comment: @the_velour_fog, yes, I like them too. Some people frown on it though (for good or less good reasons) and would tell you to use the longer, less legible (IMO) but more portable Bourne form. At the shell prompt, I'd use the shorter C-like form, in scripts I tend to use the longer ones, but it doesn't harm showing the alternative forms here once in  a while.

Comment: cool, the explanations are really useful too. there is a backtick missing at the beginning of `$#array, reminiscent of ksh's` messing up the rest of the formating of the bullet point. I tried to add it in an edit but there is a 6 char minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel will do this easily, and process multiple files at once as a bonus:

```
parallel /home/user/scriptModelise.pl {} ">>" {.}.csv ::: *"$foobar"*
```

That will cause an error if no files matched `*"$foobar"*`, so you should either check that first, or use `find` to pipe the names in, or set bash's `failglob` option.